# Where are my bash terminals?

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal

I have some bash terminals open yesterday in VM. But today, when I logged in to VM, it was like its restarted, that is I cannot find any terminal UI window. When I checked System Monitor, I can still see those bash terminals still running. How can I get back to them? Or its no more possible? (I want to copy paste output of some commands in those terminal sessions.)

PS: I am on CentOS Linux 7

Comment: Typically terminals are killed when you logout; you may be able to persist pseudo-terminals across sessions with screen or tmux, but those still won’t survive a true reboot.

Comment: When I connect to CentOS remote machine from Windows 10 remote desktop, it opens xrdp with xvnc session. Mentioning this because it might have something to do with. I never logged out, just killed remote desktop. In fact, just now I tried killing remote desktop and reconnecting, still all windows are there

Comment: if you left a session logged in overnight and it was gone in the morning, you should talk to a sysadmin. Maybe it was rebooted, maybe it was configured to log you out after inactivity. We can only guess.

Comment: am I supposed see those terminal in Resource monitor even after logged out?